# How to rewrite magento website to new domain

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I have magento website in `custom.com` domain, and now I want to access complete frontend website content from one more domain also says `custom1.com`. Admin url will be same as `custom.com/admin`.

I have pointed new domain to `custom.com` server.

Is it possible to rewrite using `htaccess` rewrite rule, If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have run Multistore in magento2 by adding code in index.php.

I have replaced code in index.php 

    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);

to 

$params = $_SERVER;
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'abc.com':
    case 'www.abc.com':
     $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website_code1';
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
    break;
    case 'test.com':
    case 'test2.co.uk':
    case 'www.test2.co.uk':
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base';
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
    break;
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

This code is working fine for me,hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to manage multiple stores with your Magento 1.9 instance. You require each store to have a different domain. Here are the basic steps.

1. Create the additional store in System -> Manage Stores. the [documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html) is found [here](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html).
2. Setup the secure and unsecure URLs in **System -> Configuration -> General -> Web**. You will have to select the scope for each website before entering the website URLs. The Documentation for [scope configuration](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html) can be found [here](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html).
3. Update the .htaccess file in the root directory of your Magento website. Here is an example of the code where **base** is the code for the first website and **web** is the code for the second website.

   ```
   SetEnvIf Host www\.custom\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
   SetEnvIf Host www\.custom\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
   SetEnvIf Host www\.custom1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=web
   SetEnvIf Host www\.custom1t\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
   ```
4. Clear your cache to make your changes effective.

We are assuming your web server is already configured to recognize both the **www.custom.com** and the **www.custom1.com** host names pointing to the same Magento root directory.